# Explanation of Hadith Needed

Tags: hadith

I don't [understand](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/70) this hadith. If hell breaths in the summer and this is why it's hot in the summer, then how come it's winter in Australia whereas it's summer in India for example.

Comment: Relevant: [How to Understand the Hadith About Hell and the Seasons?](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2015/06/29/how-to-understand-the-hadith-about-hell-and-the-seasons/)

Comment: This seems to be about the same question as [What is meant by this hadith about season change?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48139/what-is-meant-by-this-hadith-about-season-change)

Comment: Yes, but what's the answer to it?